# Explanation of how this Lebesgue integral is 1

Tags: measure-theory, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f(x) =$

$x$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$,

$1$ is $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$

The $f(x) = x$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, will give infinity many 'heights' for rectangles against the function. And these heights that will approach infinity themselves. Although the width for each rectangle will be infinitesimally small...so how does this resolve to a value of $1$?

Comment: First prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ has measure zero. Then explain to yourself that if $f = g$ outside a set of measure zero, then $\int f = \int g$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is a null set. So for the purposes of the Lebesgue integral, your function is $\equiv 1$.

Comment: you are thinking about Riemann integration with these rectangle things? If so, that is not good. the function is not Riemann integrable